# INTERNAL ERROR: Error while creating merge control point

Tags: merge, anylogic

I have created a relatively simple road network, using the GIS element of AnyLogic itself. Then after adding in GIS points and creating routes, I converted it to a space markup element with roads on it.
I compiled and ran the simulation just to test it and it worked.

As soon as I add a car and try running it on any of the roads, this error shows up:

Error during model startup:
root:
roadNetwork : INTERNAL ERROR: Error while creating merging control point

This is my space markup element with roads:

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Just for reference, I only ran the most basic car agent flowchart, as below:

[image]

Any advice would be helpful, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I did not tamper with the roads or intersections or anything on the roadnetwork and am using the exact one that was converted by AnyLogic from the GIS map and routes to the space markup with roads.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the conversion did not fully work. It looks correct but some road may not actually be connected.

Put on your Sherlock Holmes head and find out when it stops breaking by removing roads bit by bit.

Also check that you actually only have 1 road network that contains all road elements.